# How to make image to fit the size of another image (dragging)

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, easeljs

How can i make one image to be inside another image. And if goes out of the container image to be not visible.

[Example here](http://classic.makesweet.com/example/thumb/400/x200807184880cdb759cbc547448785_1216401009884_back-tattoo_400x300_25_hip.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/NXwsm/850/)

HTML:

```
<div class="imgWrap">
    <img class="img1" src="http://cf.mp-cdn.net/a5/15/54eb476ff1a5f20f69942605df14-was-the-bombing-of-hiroshima-and-nagasaki-justified.jpg" />
    <img class="img2" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgWrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img1, .img2 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
//Finds the smallest height
var height = $(".img1").height();
if ($(".img2").height() < height) height = $(".img2").height();

//Finds the smallest width
var width = $(".img1").width();
if ($(".img2").width() < width) width = $(".img2").width();

//Sets height and width of image
$(".imgWrap").css({"height":height,"width":width});
```

Comment: No, I need one image to be container for another image.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a _container_? Do you mean a literal container or something that appears to be containing the other image? [Apparent container](http://jsfiddle.net/NXwsm/853/) and [literal container](http://jsfiddle.net/NXwsm/850/) examples here.